# Cap deploy failed when running "rvm rvmrc trust"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

After first success deployment using Capistrano, running cap deploy failed:

no old releases to clean up

Triggering after callbacks for `deploy'

> 2013-04-16 10:59:15 executing `rvm:trust_rvmrc'
>   executing "rvm rvmrc trust /home/app/xxxx/releases/20130415225133"
>
> ```
> servers: ["191.199.74.146"]
> [191.199.74.146] executing command
> ```
>
> **[err :: 191.199.74.146] Marked /home/app/xxxx/releases/20130415225133/.rvmrc as trusted - failed**

Error occurred when putting following code to the deploy.rb:

```
namespace :assets do
  desc "Precompile assets locally and then rsync to app servers"
  task :precompile, :only => { :primary => true } do
    run_locally "mkdir -p public/__assets; mv public/__assets public/assets;"
    run_locally "bundle exec rake assets:clean_expired; bundle exec rake assets:precompile;"
    servers = find_servers :roles => [:app], :except => { :no_release => true }
    servers.each do |server|
      run_locally "rsync -av ./public/assets/ #{user}@#{server}:#{current_path}/public/assets/;"
    end
    run_locally "mv public/assets public/__assets"
  end
end
```

**Update**

I executed rvm rvmrc trust on my local, also failed..

> xxxx-iMac:iv Owner$ rvm rvmrc trust Marked
>   /Users/Owner/Documents/workspace/iv/.rvmrc as trusted - failed

Comment: I'm also having this problem, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried running 'rvm rvmrc trust'? Or delete .rvmrc try again.